# Can jdk 21 virtual threads execute tasks concurrently?

Tags: java, openjdk-21

According to https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/core/virtual-threads.html#GUID-DC4306FC-D6C1-4BCC-AECE-48C32C1A8DAA

> Like a platform thread, a virtual thread is also an instance of java.lang.Thread. However, a virtual thread isn't tied to a specific OS thread. A virtual thread still runs code on an OS thread. However, when code running in a virtual thread calls a blocking I/O operation, the Java runtime suspends the virtual thread until it can be resumed. The OS thread associated with the suspended virtual thread is now free to perform operations for other virtual threads.

Virtual threads are based on platform threads, there are multiple virtual threads in a thread, can I have two virtual threads in a thread perform a task at the same time?

Two virtual threads in a thread perform a task at the same time

Comment: “Two virtual threads in a thread” is a wrong mindset. There are *n* virtual threads distributed over *m* platform threads. A virtual thread can resume its work on a different platform thread than it ran before the suspension. While a platform thread is busy running one virtual thread, all other virtual threads are free to use a different platform thread, hence, may run concurrently to that virtual thread.

Comment: @Holger It dawned on me, thank you so much!!!!!!!!!!!!!